# How to hide "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience:"

Tags: reactjs

every time I launch or reload my react app I received the same console log message of "**Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: [https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools**"](https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools**%22).

How do you go by disabling this message so that when you deploy your site, it does not be seen?

[Image of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP6Py.png)

I have found other post about this, but no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console log will not be printed once you make a product build of your React application. It is only seen because you are running it in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React+Vite, then go to the file location:
"node_modules/.vite\deps/react-dom_client.js"

then remove the line:

```
if (/^(https?|file):$/.test(protocol)) {
   console.info("%cDownload the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools" + (protocol === "file:" ? "\nYou might need to use a local HTTP server (instead of file://): https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools-faq" : ""), "font-weight:bold");
}
```

If you are not using vite then just search through all the files in the node.js for:

"Download the React DevTools for a better development experience"

you will find one whereby it has a match, then just remove the code